# Expresso-store product modifiers or multiple entries?

Tags: expresso-store, modifiers

**Product 2**

This would be a single product that is either a **download** OR *physical* product. Ideally this would be a single entry as the data remains the same - it’s simply the end product that varies in format and price… so my questions are:

1. **Question 2a - 1:** Can we handle the product ‘type’ with modifiers, is this the best way to manage this?
2. **Question 2a - 2:** If a physical product is chosen is it easy to add postage? (digital download has no postage)
3. **Question 2a - 3:** Depending on the type chosen can we vary the email that is sent to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, unless we have free shipping on the physical products. Currently modifiers can not change the postage, so you always have the same shipping amount per entry.

The solution would be multiple entries, then perhaps relate these to a 'parent' that houses the 'shared' details.